# Acting on an element in onRender doesn't work

Tags: marionette

When I try to act on some HTML elements in the `onRender` method (or in a `item:rendered` callback), it fails.

Example:

```
Bars.EditGallery = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
  template: 'bars/edit_gallery'
  className: 'edit-gallery'

  onRender: ->
    # If I just write @$('select').chosen(), it doesn't work
    # despite the jQuery object contains what I expect.
    # To get it working, I have to write:
    callback = -> @$('select').chosen()
    setTimeout(callback, 0)
```

It's the same with others actions, like giving the focus to a field.
How do you deal with that? The trick with `setTimeout` works but it is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/358).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when the templates used for rendering are loaded asynchronously. I thought I a pull request had fixed this in a recent release. What version of Marionette are you using?

But it looks like you're using JST, anyways, so that shouldn't be the problem. Is there anything else in your setup that is causing the render to happen asynchronously?

It seems likely that there is some asynchronous issue happening, though. Since using `setTimeout` fixes the problem, that makes me think the rendering is not completing before the `onRender` method is called.

Also - it can be hard tell if the jQuery selector is actually returning the object you want, right away. If you're using console.log to check the selector, this may be giving false results. `console.log` is itself asynchronous (in most browsers, anyways... not sure about all) which means the request to log the item gets queued up at the end of the event loop. It's likely that the DOM element is available by the time the logging happens.

FWIW: I use `onRender` for this exact purpose on a regular basis, and I've never had to use `setTimeout` to make it work. So my assumption is something funny going on with the rendering process, related to async stuff.

Comment: I noticed that the problem does not occur when I use $(selector) instead of this.$(selector).